# Dynamic email content using Gmail

Tags: php, email, csv, gmail, mailing-list

There is any way (maybe via Chrome extensions) to send a few of messages with dynamic content via Gmail?

For example, if I have in a csv file:

```
NAME                EMAIL                   PET     FOOD BRAND DISCOUNT
Charlie Brown       goodgrief@peanuts.com   dog     Alpo       5
Dr. Claw            nexttime@gadget.com     cat     Iams       10
Jim Henson          jim@muppets.org         frog    Easy Green 15
Shaggy Rogers       zoinks@scoobydoo.com    dog     Alpo       5
Walt Disney         walt@disney.com         mouse   Magic      20
Mike Tyson          mike@punchout.com       cat     Iams       10
```

and in the body of email I need to insert something like that:

```
Dear {NAME}, For a limited time, we are offering {DISCOUNT}% discount
on {FOOD BRAND} food for your {PET}.
```

Also each email recipient must be included by `{EMAIL}` field from csv file.

I have not a large number of emails to send that. It is about 30 of them, but I would like to automatize that since I already have all needed data in csv file.

Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to compile the html page (which will be sent to the recipient) with PHP and send it then and do it for each recipient.

Here's simple example:

```
<?php
$file = fopen('youcsvfile.csv', 'r');

while ($client = fgetscsv($file))
    mail($client[1], 'Special offer', compileHtml($client));

/**
 * Build HTML page to be sent to clients
 * @param array $client
 * @return string
 */
function compileHtml($client) {
    return "<html>...Dear " . $client[0] . ", for a limited time, we are offering " . $client[4] . " discount on " . $client[3] . " food for your " . $client[2] . " <more html code></html>";
}
```

Read [mail](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mail.php) function documentation for more info.